# Python Splitting String and Sorting Alphabetically

Tags: python

Can somebody please help me to create a python program whereby the unsorted list is split up into groups of 2, arranged alphabetically within their groups of two. The program should then create a new list in alphabetical order by taking the next greatest letter from the correct pair. Please don't tell me to do this in a different way as my method must take place as is written above. Thanks :)

```
unsorted = ['B', 'D', 'A', 'G', 'F', 'E', 'H', 'C']

n = 4
num = float(len(unsorted))/n
l = [ unsorted [i:i + int(num)] for i in range(0, (n-1)*int(num), int(num))]
l.append(unsorted[(n-1)*int(num):])

print(l)


complete = unsorted.split()
print(complete)
```

Comment: `my method must take place as is written above` Why? Homework?

Comment: You should really try to figure homework out on your own. You already have the tools you need.

Comment: What's the expected output? Show an example please.

Comment: @JoeIddon In general, they come with silly constraints meaning answers addressing them are usually only helpful to OP and are generally of lower quality :-(

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to turn `unsorted` into the following list:

```
['D', 'G', 'F', 'H']
```

If that is the case, I have modified your code so that it produces the correct output.

```
unsorted = ['B', 'D', 'A', 'G', 'F', 'E', 'H', 'C']

n = 4
num = float(len(unsorted))/n
l = [ unsorted [i:i + int(num)] for i in range(0, (n-1)*int(num), int(num))]
l.append(unsorted[(n-1)*int(num):])

# This part has been added in. It sorts each sublist,
# then takes the second element (the character further along the alphabet)
for i in range(len(l)):
    l[i] = sorted(l[i])[1]

print(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are looking for `['D', 'G', 'F', 'H']`, I think the following code is similar to yours but a little clearer :

```
a = ['B', 'D', 'A', 'G', 'F', 'E', 'H', 'C']
```

Iterate over pairs of items in list, `a[i:i+2]`, using a list comprehension, and sort the items in each pair in a reversed alphabetic order using `sorted(list,reverse=True)`:

```
groups = [ sorted(a[i:i+2],reverse=True) for i in range(0,len(a),2)]
```

Iterate over the sorted groups, selecting the first item of a pair

```
result = [i[0] for i in groups]
```